# Center image but don't make the whole line a link

Tags: css

I have a logo which is a link to my homepage
I want to center it so only the image itself will be link while the white spaces on the logo sides will not.
I know I can use `display: block` or `display:table` but it makes the whole line a link.
Is it possible to center an element but keep it with its original size?

Here is the relevant code :

```
<header class="site-header" id="site-header" role="banner">
        <a href="https://smartbyte.blog">
            <img class="header-image" src="image.png" height="270" width="600" />
        </a>
```

The relevant class is `header-image`

Comment: Is your logo an ´img´ element or a block with a background?

Comment: Please post the code. Currently your question looks like *I have an apple. I know I can use a dishwasher to clean my apple but I don't want to turn it on. How can I eat my apple that it remains green although it was red?*

Comment: @smnbbv just eat the apple dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control your image without adding style to the header, you can simply add fixed width to `a` and make it `display:block` (since you know the width of your image) then simply use **margin:auto**:

```css
a {
  display: block;
  max-width: 400px;
  width:100%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid red; /* To show it only takes width of image */
}

a img {
  vertical-align: top; /* To remove white space */
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header" id="site-header" role="banner">
  <a href="https://smartbyte.blog">
    <img class="header-image" src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" height="270" width="400" />
  </a>
</header>
```

Or use `display:table` and you don't need to specify a width:

```css
a {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  border:1px solid red; /* To show it only takes width of image */
}
a img {
 vertical-align:top; /* To remove white space*/
 max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header" id="site-header" role="banner">
  <a href="https://smartbyte.blog">
    <img class="header-image" src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" height="270" width="400" />
  </a>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, the image width isn't static and changes according to the browser size, but I guess I can still apply specific class over the `a` tag , right ?

Comment: @SagiLow yes right, and you can then consider my second solution where you don't need the width ;)

Comment: @SagiLow i also updated my code to make it responsive on browser resize

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you're using an `img` element, simply wrap it up with an `a` element, itself placed within another element (e.g. a `div`).

```
<div class="link-container">
  <a href="homepage.com">
    <img alt="My website" src="image.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

And the CSS code:

```
.link-container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Currently the class applied to the img element, you are saying it isn't possible this way and I should apply it to the parent element ?

Comment: Yes. You'll always have to style some of the `img` parents at some point so long as it is contained within another `a` (which in your case is necessary since you want your `img` to behave like a link) and you don't want the whole line to be clickable.